# How to shrink wrap image in wxScrolledWindow

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a frame that has some stuff at the top, and a wxScrolledWindow below. The scrolled window contains an image selected by the user. I want the frame to shrink-wrap it so that background never shows in the scrolled window. I am using a BoxSizer in the frame. Everything works perfectly until the user drags a border to increase the viewing area. He takes it too far, and background shows. I have tried at least a dozen methods, but I cannot get the window's border to snap back when the user drags the border beyond where the scrollbars disappear. When the image is loaded, the scrolled window calls SetMaxClientSize() with the right numbers, but it has no effect. A couple of pictures will help. I have just dragged the right border to the right, increasing the viewing area. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I want the border to snap back so it looks like this:

[image]

Windows 7 x64, wxWidgets 2.9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-implement the size event handler.  If the new size is larger than you want, modify it to the largest you accept.   Then call the base implementation.

```
void MyFrame::OnSize(wxSizeEvent& event)
{
    wxSize new_size = event.GetSize()

    wxSize max_size = ... calculate max size ....

    if ( new_size.GetHeight() > max_size.GetHeight() {
        new_size.SetHeight(  max_size.GetHeight() );
    if ( new_size.GetWidth() > max_size.GetWidth() {
        new_size.SetWidth(  max_size.GetWidth() );

    event.SetSize( new_size );
    wxFrame::OnSize( event );
```

Also, be aware of this note in the documentation:

> Important : Sizers ( see Sizers Overview ) rely on size events to
>   function correctly. Therefore, in a sizer-based layout, do not forget
>   to call Skip on all size events you catch (and don't catch size events
>   at all when you don't need to).

Comment: In your code, new_size is never referenced. What did you intend? Thanks!

Comment: @DaveNadler Good catch!  Fixed.

Comment: Unless I'm confused, that doesn't work. Consider the case where the frame is sized really short vertically: In this case the max required width for the frame's client area is the bitmap width **plus** the width of the vertical scrollbar, no?

Comment: this does not work. The frame is resized to larger than desired even when the event size is reduced and propagated as you suggested. I'll post a picture below...

Answer (score 0):

Ravenspoint's answer doesn't seem to work (using wxWidgets 3.0.3 or 2.8.12). The frame is resized larger than desired even when the event size is reduced and propagated as you suggested. Here's an example:
[image]

Comment: Have you stepped through using a debugger to ensure that the code is being called and the max_size is correctly calculated?

Comment: @ravenspoint Certainly I checked the size calculation and reduction in the debugger... If you're interested see code at [link]www.nadler.com/backups/20180127_MapWinTest.zip and/or discussion at  [link]https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44197